# Proof of properties of paths with distinct parities

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to work on this theorem, but I can't reach anywhere.

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be paths in a graph $G$ such that the end of $P$ is the same as the beginning of $Q$. Let $u$ be the first vertex of $P$ and $v$ the last vertex of $Q$. Prove (or disprove) that if $P$ and $Q$ have distinct parities, then $PQ$ has a odd path from $u$ to $v$ or $PQ$ has a odd cycle.

Comment: More generally, if there is an odd-length walk from $a $ to $b $, then there is an odd-length path from $a$ to $b $ or there is an odd-length cycle.

Comment: Hint for the proof: The walk either is a path (==> done) or has a loop. In the latter case, take a minimal loop. It is a cycle.  If it is an odd-length cycle, you are done. If not, remove it from the walk, and proceed by induction.

Comment: HI! Why is the minimal loop a cycle?

Comment: If it ever comes back to a point other than its starting point (or to its starting point, but earlier than at its end), you can pluck out an even smaller loop out of it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense, but how can you guarantee that the loop isn't a closed walk, for instance, a walk that goes from a vertex u to a vertex v and back to vertex u?

Comment: A loop *has* to be a closed walk! I'm looking for a cycle at this point.

Comment: Yes, but I mean... a closed walk is not always a cycle. How can you guarantee that it is indeed a cycle, in this case? I think that I can state that if there were repeated edges in the walk, I could just remove all but one copies of them and get a path, but would it be odd?